# How to create actions column use layout block magento2

Tags: magento2.1.5, transaction, customer-grid

I use layout block to create grid page, but it does't inclue actions column
so can I create dropdown actions edit and delete use layout block
file Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn(
        'actions',
        [
            'header'=>__('Action'),
            'index'=>'actions'
        ]
    );
```

My grid page [image]

the grid page i want

### [image: Heading]

Comment: have you followed UI component ?

Answer (score 2):

This can help you for adding new action in to the grid which is created through the Grid.php file.

```
  $this->addColumn(
        'action', [
            'header' => __('Action'),
            'type' => 'action',
            'getter' => 'getId',
            'actions' => [
                [
                    'caption' => __('Edit'),
                    'url' => ['base' => '*/*/edit'],
                    'field' => 'id',
                ],
                [
                    'caption' => __('Delete'),
                    'url' => ['base' => '*/*/delete'],
                    'field' => 'id',
                ],
            ],
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'index' => 'stores',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-action',
        ]
    );
```